# Problem rendering content of Material UI components in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Text content of Material UI components is not rendered to final HTML. Render method of my component looks like:

```
render() {
    const panel = this.props.panel;
    return (<div>{panel.title}
        <Card className={style.panel}>
            <CardHeader>atesta {panel.title}</CardHeader>
            <CardContent>
                btestb
                <div className={style.fields}>
                    {this.renderFields()}
                </div>
                <div className={style.query}>
                    {this.renderQuery()}
                </div>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
                {this.renderAdds()}
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And result in browser (copied via dev-tools in browser) is:

```
<div>Všechny kurzy
    <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root panel__2c68Z MuiPaper-elevation1 MuiPaper-rounded">
        <div class="MuiCardHeader-root">
            <div class="MuiCardHeader-content"/>
        </div>
        <div class="MuiCardContent-root">btestb<div class="fields__3WM0i"/>
            <div class="query__2pUWn">
                <div>
                    <table class="MuiTable-root list__3CCEF">
                        <tbody class="MuiTableBody-root">
                            <tr class="MuiTableRow-root item__3Owps">
                                <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body"/>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="MuiTableRow-root item__3Owps">
                                <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body"/>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="MuiTableRow-root item__3Owps">
                                <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body"/>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="MuiCardActions-root MuiCardActions-spacing">
            <div class="buttons__2F1y2">
                <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text" tabindex="0" type="button">
                    <span class="MuiButton-label">Přidat kurz</span>
                    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"/>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see string "Všechny kurzy" (which is value of panel.title) on the first line but empty `<div class="MuiCardHeader-content"/>` where panel.title is also used along with atesta string. String btestb is also correctly visible in final HTML.

Any idea what's wrong? I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CardHeader` does not render children. Instead you should be using the `title` and/or `subheader` props.

So instead of:

```
<CardHeader>atesta {panel.title}</CardHeader>
```

you should have:

```
<CardHeader title={`atesta ${panel.title}`} />
```

or:

```
<CardHeader title={<>atesta {panel.title}</>} />
```

Documentation: https://material-ui.com/api/card-header/#props